# Ansible enable audit logging

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I am looking for audit logging in Ansible. I am running my playbook as root, but i want to write in log who the local user is executing the playbook. Please help in enabling logs to show user.

Comment: Create log file with user permissions in advance?

Comment: Not user permissions. When I execute a playbook, i am looking for in logs user who initiated. Right now it shows root. I am looking for user in particular.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to audit logging outside of Ansible. As Ansible is by its design decentral. But as Ansible uses by default ssh to execute commands on remote hosts there is no need for an audit solution specific to Ansible. As anyone how is able to execute commands on a remote host via Ansible is also able to run those commands via ssh a solution only covering Ansible wouldn't be enough.

Just setup [auditd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd) and make sure that [commands run with sudo](https://blog.shichao.io/2015/04/22/auditing_user_tty_and_root_commands_with_auditd_on_ubuntu.html) are logged.